# fancybox IFrame print

Tags: jquery, iframe, printing, fancybox

I would like to print whatever is displayed in the fancybox IFrame popup.
How to do it? Currently print just prints everything underneath which is not what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#printBtn").click(function() {
    $('#myIframe')[0].print();
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I assume this goes on the Site.master page but how to call it on the fancyBox overlay window. My IFrame contains a link which is based on a list of http addresses which are not know in advance.

Comment: You would need to have a print button somewhere on your page which calls this code. I'll update my example for this.

Comment: So I need to make another aspx page and within the IFrame and display the print button + the other generated http link right?

Comment: That would depend on how your site is structured and what control you have over the content of the popup.

Comment: No control over the content of the popup unfortunately. What is the best way to just have an aspx page with print and close button and right below (on the same page) have another page fully displayed?

Comment: For example my aspx page has Close/Print buttons at the top and the webpage below in an IFrame (with scrollbars), but when I try to print it only prints what is currently visible on the screen (1 page) I can just pop up another window but that's not neat.